# TCP stream relay

Tags: linux, tcp

I have two program communicating with TCP/IP.
this works fine.

program A opens a TCP socket.
program B connects to this socket.
program B gives data to program A.
everything works very fine.

but when i put a relay between A and B
and just pass the byte stream, something goes wrong.

program C opens two TCP socket(socket1, socket2).
program B connects to this socket(socket1).
program A connects to this socket(socket2).

program C relays TCP strem from B to A with following code.
(this is based on linux)

```
char buf[BUFSIZE];
while(1){
        // recv a packet segment
        if( my_recv(socket1, buf, BUFSIZE) <= 0 ){
                return 0;
        }

        if( send(socket2, buf, BUFSIZE, MSG_NOSIGNAL) != BUFSIZE ){
            return 0;
        }
}
```

my_recv is a wrapper for recv to guarantee it will recv
request size.

```
int my_recv(int sd, char* p, unsigned int len){
    // recv a packet segment
    unsigned int ssize=0;
    int d;
    while(ssize < len){         
        if( (d=recv( sd, p+ssize, len - ssize, 0))<=0){
            return -1;
        }
        ssize += d;         
    }
    return ssize;
}
```

this works fine for first time.
but after few seconds, everything is messed up.

I have debugged program A and B.
there is nothing wrong with them.
they send and recv in correct order but it seems
that relay gives false data...

some advise would be appreciated.

thank you in advance.

Comment: my_recv is a wrapper for recv to guarantee it will recv request size.

Comment: But that also means it would block until buffer is filled up, and data relay would stop until that happens - and this is messed up

Comment: but TCP is lossless protocol. I think data passing can be delayed, but I don't know why corrupted contents are delivered.

Comment: solved. it was some stupid mistake from something else. nothing was wrong with program...

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming each read fills the buffer. You have to use the count returned by the recv() call as the length argument to the send() call.

```
while ((count = recv(fd, buffer, sizeof buffer, 0)) > 0)
  send(fd, buffer, count, 0);
```

Comment: to solve that problem I have coded my_recv, which guarantees to recv requested size to buffer.

Comment: @daehee But it can't guarantee that. What if the transmission isn't a multiple of BUFSIZE? That technique also adds unnecessary latency. Use the two lines of code above.

Comment: Thank you... but I have tried that already but the result is same...

Comment: @dahee I'm afraid I just don't believe that. It's been working for me for over 20 years.

Comment: problem has solved!! I am really sorry, it was a STUPID mistake from somewhere else. there was nothing wrong with TCP and relay server. thank you anyway!

Comment: @dahee I'm afraid I just don't believe that either. Your code posted here remains flawed, and you need something like the above to fix it.

Comment: I fixed my code as you suggested. thank you!